# Getting java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect in eclipse.
I am working behind corporate proxy settings.

**Code:**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1202)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:966)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
at URLConnectionReader.main(URLConnectionReader.java:9)
```

I have set the proxy setting in Preference-->Network Setting as shown in image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use  `System.setProperty()` method and set the proxy like below.

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "webcache.example.com");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
```

or you can use `Proxy` class

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("webcache.example.com", 8080));
HttpURLConnection connection =(HttpURLConnection)new URL("your URL").openConnection(proxy);
```

[you can check this documentaion for more info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html)

**FYI**

`Eclipse IDE` may need access to the **Internet** for some plugins install and update.  You have to configure the proxy settings in Eclipse, if you are behind **proxy**. This is for your Eclipse not for java code

Comment: I have tried the above one as well. its now working. I have tried with -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.*****.com
-Dhttp.proxyPort=**** in eclpse.ini file as well. Still the same. Any idea how to resolve this issue

Comment: Try adding this in ini file -Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient

Comment: You can pass this commands as vm arguments...Run -> Run configurations -> Select your project. Then “Arguments”.then bottom tab for VM

Comment: No luck. Still the same. Can I know whether the cacerts under jre\lib\security folder plays a role in each call from eclispe

Comment: Not for an HTTP connection.  (They do for an HTTPS connection, but if this was a certs problem you would not get Connection Refused.)

Comment: Try running the application from the command line to eliminate Eclipse from the list of possible causes.